# Как в eclipse подключить библиотеку google_play_services при разработке под android?

Tags: android, google-play, eclipse, библиотеки

У меня вот такая проблема: следуя [инструкциям](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=ru) пытался подключить библиотеку google_play_services, для добавления рекламы в своё приложение. В sdk-manager залезал и библиотеку инсталлировал. Но вот подключить её никак не могу. Захожу, как и сказано, в properties->android и жму add, а там пусто. Только appcompat_v7, который подключается еще при создании приложения. Может кто подсказать, что делать? Вот чувствую, что что-то простое упустил: галочку где-то не поставил или еще что.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пункт 2. Выберите Android и нажмите Add (Добавить). Найдите проект google-play-services_lib (в вашей папке с `sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`) и нажмите OK, чтобы добавить библиотеку сервисов Google Play.

**Update:**

Вначале нужно данную биб-ку добавить в workspace:

> Import the library project into your Eclipse workspace. Click File Import, select Android Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.

А затем уже add делать

Comment: Да, так и есть. Про то, что надо импортировать, я и забыл. Спасибо большое.